# Show <div> tags inside in one line

Tags: html, css

I have a `<table>` and I put  more than 6 `<div>`s in one `td` then I change the `display:inline` to show these `<div>`s inside together.

But it just show at most 5 `<div>`s in first line and show others in in another line below of first line!

where is wrong?

This is my code:

```
   <tr>
     <td>
        <div id="navigation"> Home </div>
        <div id="navigation"> Item1</div>
        <div id="navigation">  Item2 </div>
        <div id="navigation">  Item3</div>
        <div id="navigation"> Item4  </div>
        <div id="navigation">  Item5 </div>
        <div id="navigation"> Item 6 </div>
        <div id="navigation">   Item 7</div>
     </td >
   </tr>
```

CSS Code:

```
#navigation{
    display:inline;
    padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
```

this is design view:

[image]

Comment: Could you show the CSS for this?

Comment: The width of the inner exceeds with of outer?

Comment: i think this is semantically incorrect. divs inside a table feels very wrong.

Comment: In this context you are using your divs like spans...why not use spans?

Comment: because of `td width` apply width to td and divide them equally to all div or how you want to divide but divide them this will work am sure

Comment: set float:left to each div.
btw, it's bad practise to use more than once the same ID, use instead CLASS

Comment: Yeah this like lifting a trashcan lid and finding mold everywhere. :C ew. Hope things get better Milad!

Answer (score 3):

You are using `table` for layout, use div's instead, ya, surely it won't throw you any error but what you are doing is semantically not correct...

The correct way and a better way to have this is as an unordered list, with `display: inline-block;` CSS property

```
<ul>
   <li>Demo 1</li>
   <li>Demo 2</li>
   <li>Demo 3</li>
   <li>Demo 4</li>
   <li>Demo 5</li>
</ul>

ul li {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

You can also wrap the `ul` inside an `nav` which is HTML5 element to provide it a meaning that yes, this is a navigation, you'll be probably nesting `a` element inside the holder so using `display: block;` for `a` element will make sense

Answer (score 1):

First off you can't have multiple elements with the same ID. Change `id="navigation"` to `class="navigation"` on the elements.

Secondly you can then use this CSS:

```
.navigation
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This will make those elements all appear in a row.

Comment: @MiladSobhkhiz - it works most definitely - http://jsfiddle.net/yURNn/, they're all in a row.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no fixed table width, the tables maximum width is the window width.

See this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7QLPW/1/

One Table with specified width and one without

```
<table width="500px">
...

<table>
```

The first one does not break as soon as the window width gets too small, the second one does.

Comment: I compare the fixed width solution with yours. I thought you don't want the divs to start a new line?

Answer (score 0):

What is the width of your table, full layout or how many column you have.

you can see what I try for your issue

```
http://fiddle.jshell.net/yNF4n/
```

Comment: this <td> has `colspan` property that its value is "2"

I think this the reason!

Comment: I am sure about your table width is the main problem. Play with with and you got your goal....